# Difference between STOP instance and SUSPEND instance in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was created an instance in Google Cloud Platform. I use this instance 2 to 4 days in a week. So, I want to close my instance for rest of the days to save my billing charges. So, what is best option for me. `Stop` the instance or `Suspend` the instance? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please have a look at the documentation [Suspending and resuming an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/suspend-resume-instance):

> **Suspending an instance differs from stopping an instance in the following ways**:
>
> - Suspended instances preserve the guest OS memory, device state, and application state.
> - **Google charges for the storage necessary to save instance memory.**
> - You can only suspend an instance for up to 60 days. After 60 days, the instance is automatically moved to the TERMINATED state.

and at the article [Stopping and starting an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#billing):

> Instances that are in a TERMINATED state are not charged for
> per-second usage and do not count toward your regional CPU quota, so
> you can choose to stop instances that you are not using, saving you
> from being charged for instances that aren't active. After you are
> ready, you can come back and start the same instances again, with the
> same instance properties, metadata, and resources.
>
> **Your instances are not charged for per-second usage while in the
> TERMINATED state but any resources attached to the virtual machine,
> such as static IPs and persistent disks, are charged until they are
> deleted.**

As a result, it's better to stop your VM instance, to avoid extra changes for keeping instance's memory.

In addition, please have a look at the article [Save money by stopping and starting Compute Engine instances on schedule](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/save-money-by-stopping-and-starting-compute-engine-instances-on-schedule).

Comment: The referenced article has been superseded by a the built-in [Instance Schedules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) feature